# Should I give a client more logo options after refusing the initial designs?

Tags: print-design, logo, client-relations, freelance

A client requested a logo design and branding for his start-up; it's business consultancy company.

**The deal includes 3 logo design options** with 7 items designed for the brand, for X amount of money. 50% of payment is due after agreeing to the logo, the other 50% after full work is done.

Their name is uBrand, and I have done 3 designs at first (two of them are full name "Unique Brand" logotypes). He rejected them and said he wants 3 designs of a "uBrand" logotype (not the full name). I provided two more logo options and an edited one of the previous sent logos. Now he rejects them all! And he refuses to pay.

**Should I try with a new concept design for him?**

**Or should I make him choose one (do some amendments for him) and proceed as stated in the contract?**

I did everything he stated in the brief "simple, logo type, very simple twist in font, clear and works on all mediums" >> *should not be a challenge but he seems to not know what he wants.*

He said they're a retro style but the truth is he doesn't even give a good reason for refusing them and he says he likes simple logos like Google's.

Comment: If he hasn't payed you anything yet I'd likely just stop working with him. He doesn't sound like a client that I'd enjoy working with

Comment: You walk away with the lesson learnt that you ask for 50% up front.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the logo of Google is "simple"...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing three things from your contract:

**1) A down payment.** When writing up a contract, you get a percentage of money *before you do any work,* to cover exactly this scenario (that you do everything and the client hates it and refuses to pay).

**2) A kill fee,** which is an amount (flat or percentage) which is paid when one side or the other cancels the contract (which is what he's doing by refusing to pay).

**3) A line stating that beyond three versions, the client has to pay hourly.**

Do not do more logo options for him. Your contract said three. He refused them all. He has paid you nothing.

I would declare the project cancelled and at this point walk away, and learn how to write a better contract for the next time.